# Python-Django csv.writer

Tags: python, django

How can I handle Nonetype in smart_str writer.writerow?, this is how i export data to excel,

I used smart_str this is my full code, I hope this will clarify or understand my problem and i hope this will solve the problem

I have 3 models that involves here

StudentsEnrollmentRecord
Student_Users(field) class name StudentProfile
and under StudentProfile i have another foriegnkey Parent_Users(ParentsProfile)

```
def downloadcv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    # decide the file name
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="StudentEnrollmentRecord.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))

    # write the headers
    writer.writerow([
        smart_str(u"students ID"),
        smart_str(u"Fullname"),
        smart_str(u"Courses"),
        smart_str(u"Strands"),
        smart_str(u"Section"),
        smart_str(u"Payment_Type"),
        smart_str(u"Discount_Type"),
        smart_str(u"Education_Levels"),
        smart_str(u"Semester"),
        smart_str(u"ESC"),
        smart_str(u"Student_Types"),
        smart_str(u"Last_School_Attended"),
        smart_str(u"Address_OF_School_Attended"),
        smart_str(u"GWA"),
        smart_str(u"School_Year"),
        smart_str(u"Birthday"),
        smart_str(u"Citizenship"),
        smart_str(u"Religion"),
        smart_str(u"Place_Of_Birth"),
        smart_str(u"Telephone_Number"),
        smart_str(u"Gender"),
        smart_str(u"Home_Address"),
        
        
        smart_str(u"Fathers_Fullname"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers_Occupation"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers Company"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers_Gmail"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers_Educational_Attainment"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers_Contact_Number"),
        smart_str(u"Fathers Landline"),

        smart_str(u"Mothers_Fullname"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers_Occupation"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers Company"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers_Gmail"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers_Educational_Attainment"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers_Contact_Number"),
        smart_str(u"Mothers_Landline"),
        
        smart_str(u"Family_Total_Income"),
        smart_str(u"Number_Of_Siblings"),
        smart_str(u"Family_Status"),
        
        smart_str(u"Guardians_Fullname"),
        smart_str(u"Guardians_Address"),
        smart_str(u"Contact_Number"),
    ])
    # get data from database or from text file....
    yearid = request.POST.get("yearid")
    print("yearid: ", yearid)
    reports = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(School_Year=yearid).order_by('Education_Levels','-Date_Time')
    print(reports)
    for report in reports:
        writer.writerow([
            smart_str(report.id),
            smart_str(report.Student_Users),
            smart_str(report.Courses),
            smart_str(report.strands),
            smart_str(report.Section),
            smart_str(report.Payment_Type),
            smart_str(report.Discount_Type),
            smart_str(report.Education_Levels),
            smart_str(report.Semester),
            smart_str(report.ESC),
            smart_str(report.Student_Types),
            smart_str(report.Last_School_Attended),
            smart_str(report.Address_OF_School_Attended),
            smart_str(report.GWA),
            smart_str(report.School_Year.Description),
            
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Birthday) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Citizenship) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Religions) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Place_Of_Birth) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Landline) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Gender) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Unit_Number_Street + report.Student_Users.Barangay + report.Student_Users.City + report.Student_Users.AddressLine1) or "None",
            
            
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Fathers_Lastname + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Fathers_Firstname + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Fathers_Middle_Initial) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Father_Occupation) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Father_Company_Employed) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Father_Email) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Educational_AttainmentID_Father.Description) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Father_MobileNo) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Father_Landline) or "None",
            
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Maiden_LastName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_FirstName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Middle_Initial) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Occupation) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Company_Employed) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Email) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Educational_AttainmentID_Mother.Description) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_MobileNo) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Mother_Landline) or "None",
            
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Family_Total_Income.Description) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.numberOfSiblings) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Family_Status.Description) or "None",
            
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_FirstName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_Middle_Initial) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Unit_Number_Street + report.Student_Users.Barangay + report.Student_Users.City + report.Student_Users.AddressLine1) or "None",
            smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_MobileNo) or "None",
        ])
    return response if response is not None else 'None'
```

this is the error

[image]

Full traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/unidaweb/unidaproject/Homepage/views.py" in downloadcv
  389.             smart_str(report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_FirstName + report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_Middle_Initial) or "None",

Exception Type: TypeError at /downloadcv/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Can you get more context about the errror, also share the `smart_view` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `smart_str(u"Citizenship") or "unknown"` to have a fallback string

Comment: Hi, i Just update my question code, please see

Comment: You need to use parenthesis and an `or` for each expression that could return None

Comment: you could also refactor the `smart_str` function to return a string when None or take an optional default value

Comment: ahm why you need to put `or` in `smart_str(u"Citizenship")`? where it is string? and not data from the database?

Comment: you could also refactor the smart_str function to return a string when None or take an optional default value , how?

Comment: How can i refactor the `smart_str`?

Answer (score 0):

As @jujule and @May Yie said, the best thing to achive it is refactor the `smart_str` function, you can try the following:

```py
my_var_to_return = None|'string' 
return my_varto_return if my_var_to_return is not None else 'Something else'
```

One thing that is important is that you will stop the error to propagate in whatever view that use the `smart_str` function.

In case that you don't have control over `smart_str` you can make a function called `super_smart_str(mystr)` and you can do something like this:

```py
def super_smart_str(mystr):
    my_str = smart_str(mystr)
    return my_str if my_str is not None else 'Something else'
```

Then you can custom this:

```
# write the headers
writer.writerow([
    super_smart_str(u"Birthday"),
    super_smart_str(u"Citizenship"), # Will not return None values
    super_smart_str(u"Religion"),
])
```

At last you are dealing with your concatenation:

```
last_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName or "Anything else"
first_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_FirstName or "smt else" 
initial = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_Middle_Initial or "other thing"
smart_str( last_name + first_name +  initial) # Should not get any errors
```

That's it.

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: I think this should fix the error `smart_str( last_name + first_name +  initial)` the problem why you ar getting the error is because one of the variables `last_name` or `first_name` or `initial` is `None`, so you should validate it before concatenate them.

Comment: from this `last_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName or "Anything else"` and `first_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_FirstName or "smt else" ` and `initial = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_Middle_Initial or "other thing"`